# it is showing error that ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended, What to do?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select * from student_79;
DECLARE
    total_rows number(2);
BEGIN
    UPDATE student_10
    SET age = age + 2;
    IF sql%notfound THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('no student updated');
    ELSIF sql%found THEN
        total_rows :=sql%rowcount;
        dbms_output.put_line(total_rows || ' student updated ');
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: maybe error is in if else if look you wrote elsif not elseif

Comment: A PL/SQL blocks typically needs to be ended with a `/` on a separate line

Comment: Not sure, but add an / before Declare.. and one after end i.e. END; / give it a try.

Comment: What editor are you using and how are you running the two commands? They work fine for me in SQL\*Plus (except it needs a `/` after the anonymous block to run it) and in PL/SQL Developer. It may be different in SQL Developer or Toad etc.

Answer (score 0):

i check your code it is working goods no any error return.

Comment: A couple of observations not related to your error. 1) your table names suggest that you have multiple identical tables that differ only in the values of the rows/columns. If so they should be combined into 1 table. 2) You should never store 'age' of anything, as 'age' is always increasing. Store the date from which age can always be computed. 3) Given that you _are_ storing age, your update, as written, will increase the 'age' of _every_ row.  That is usually not what is intended.